# C++ Image processing data blocks into array / pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, image-processing

I have two grey scale images in txt files, one being a smaller block of the Main image. I have read the images into two different 2d vector matrices.

The Rows and the Columns of the images are:

Main: M = 768 N = 1024

SubImg: R = 49 C = 36

int R = 49; int C = 36;     //Sub Image Rows / Columns

int M = 768; int N = 1024;  //Main Image Rows / Columns

I have looped through the Main image by blocks of width: 49 and height: 36 and I want to put each block into an array, so I can compare the array with the Sub image (using Nearest Neighbor Search) to see which block has the closest result to the Sub image.

This is the code for loop of the Main image:

```
for (double bx = 0; bx < M; bx += R)
    for (double by = 0; by < N; by += C)
    {
        for (int x = 0; ((x < R) && ((bx + x) < M)); ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; ((y < C) && ((by + y) < N)); ++y)
            {
                if ((bx + x) >= M) 
                {
                    std::cout << (bx + x) << (by + y) << " ";

                }
                cout << MainIMG_2DVector[bx + x][by + y] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
    }
```

This loop displays all the blocks in one go. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to put each block into an array, so I can compare the data.
Also is it better to use a pointer instead of an array to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to compare the blocks, but as far as storing the blocks, you can make a simple Block object like this:

```
const double R = 49, C = 36;

// Block object (takes in your image 2D vector and x/y coordinates)
class Block {
public:
    Block(std::vector<std::vector<int>> *img_vector, int bx, int by);
    int compare(const Block &block) const;

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> *img_vector;
    int bx, by;
};

Block::Block(std::vector<std::vector<int>> *img_vector, int bx, int by) {
    this->img_vector = img_vector;
    this->bx = bx;
    this->by = by;
}

// Compare any two blocks
int Block::compare(const Block &block) const {
    for (int x = bx; x < bx + R; x++) {
        for (int y = by; y < by + C; y++) {
            // Do some comparing
            std::cout << "Compare " << (*img_vector)[x][y]
                << " with " << (*block.img_vector)[x][y] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0; // Return some value that indicates how they compare
}
```

And then add the image blocks to a vector:

```
// Add main image blocks to vector
std::vector<Block> main_img_blocks;
for (double bx = 0; bx < M; bx += R) {
    for (double by = 0; by < N; by += C)
        main_img_blocks.push_back(Block(&MainIMG_2DVector, bx, by));
}

// Do the same for sub image blocks...

// Invoke the compare function between 2 blocks at a time
int comp_value = main_img_blocks[0].compare(main_img_blocks[1]);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but how can I declare Block. I keep on getting this error message (no default constructor exists for class "Block". Sorry I'm new to c++. Cheers.

Comment: There are a few different ways you can do it, usually classes are defined in their own header files and implemented in a corresponding .cpp file.  A general C++ objects tutorial is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) to get you started.